# spring boot jar file wont run

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar

I have made an spring boot app and it works fine with maven but when I run it's jar file it gives an error like

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner cannot access a member of class com.cafe2.user.UserApplication with modifiers "public static"
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

i have not such an error when i am running app with maven

Comment: Can you please show the code of UserApplication https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

it was really stupid the error was because of public in boot class i just add public and it works –

```
public class UserApplication {
```